# Error Making SOAP Calls "System.CalloutException: IO Exception: PKIX path validation failed: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException"

Tags: integration, soap-api, api-client-certificate

We are making calls to an external SOAP endpoint from the Salesforce platform & it stopped working on 30th Sept 2021. Anyone having a similar issue and associated resolution?

Our endpoint is secure HTTP and using LetsEncrypt.org for the certs, they transitioned to a new root CA recently.

Answer (score 2):

I have not faced this issue recently, but because you mentioned the change on root CA (root Certification Authority), I suggest you check the [Salesforce article that explains about certificates](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000326722&type=1).

Especially the part of `/cacerts.jsp` to your instance URL and compare with the server certificate that Salesforce is communicating with. Also, check if the whole chain is present.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate chain this external endpoint is using is broken (which they would need to fix, it's not something we can take care of on the Salesforce side), or they're using a root CA that doesn't appear on [Salesforce's list of trusted certs](https://cs32.salesforce.com/cacerts.jsp).

There's not much you could do about a non-trusted root certificate, and the certificate chain thing is just a matter of making sure there's a path from the cert you're using back to the root cert.

The signing chain usually looks something like [end-user's cert] -> [intermediate cert] -> [root cert]