# What is the OpenSSL version supported by Salesforce?

Tags: integration, soap-api, api-client-certificate, openssl

We are receiving exceptions while making SOAP callouts which is explained [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/359588/error-making-soap-calls-system-calloutexception-io-exception-pkix-path-valida/359591#359591). We would like to know what version of OpenSSL is used by salesforce? and how to toggle it to support the latest version?

Answer (score 3):

Salesforce does not publish information about which version of OpenSSL they use (or if they use an alternative).

Even if they did, we have no way of choosing which version Salesforce uses. Salesforce is a "managed" platform, meaning that they take responsibility for keeping the various bits and pieces updated (and more crucially, that these updates don't break other things).